# Cannot open PDF document from C# webbrowser control

Tags: c#, pdf, webbrowser-control, 32bit-64bit

I have a SharePoint site with a document library, which opens pdf's in Adobe Acrobat (in Internet Explorer).  I would like to have the same functionality in a C# `WebBrowser` control, but when I click on the link to the document, I get the message:

> There is a problem with adobe acrobat / reader. if it is running, please exit and try again. (9:9).

I've searched and several people have had the same problem, which they blamed on building with mixed architecture, and claimed building in 32 bit would fix it.

If at all possible though, I need to have both 32 and 64 bit fuctionality.  Is there any way to get this to work?

Comment: Have you installed all updates? Also, make sure the latest version of Adobe Reader is installed and includes support for 64 bit https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/2935492

Comment: We are not using Adobe Reader.  We are using Acrobat DC Pro. I couldn't locate a 64 bit version.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Displaying pdf in WinForms webbrowser control under x64](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5904052/displaying-pdf-in-winforms-webbrowser-control-under-x64)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was indeed the architecture.  I've built it as 32 bit and it works beautifully.