# Unable to view pdf window application by using webbrowser control, (application 64bit)

Tags: c#, webbrowser-control

My application platform target is x64 and acrobat reader is 32bit unable to load pdf.
If i change my application platform target to x32 only able to view pdf.
Any possible way for my application platform target use x64 and able to view pdf ?

c# window forms application

```
    if (openFileDialog1.ShowDialog() == System.Windows.Forms.DialogResult.OK)
    {
         string strFilePath = openFileDialog1.FileName;
         webBrowser1.Url = new Uri(strFilePath);
    }
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Displaying pdf in WinForms webbrowser control under x64](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5904052/displaying-pdf-in-winforms-webbrowser-control-under-x64)

Comment: @GSerg Thanks for your comment. I have read this, but i can't find any workaround solution in this url.

Comment: There isn't one. If a 64-bit Adobe plugin is not installed, you cannot view pdfs. Alternatively, [switch to `WebView2`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45333455/11683) which can displays PDFs natively.

Comment: I tried this, this need to have .net framework 4.6.1 and above. Any suggestion for .net framework 4 ? thanks for your advice